# pkill doesn't kill process

Tags: bash, centos, centos8

I have a process running called `productivity`

```
[root@productivity ~]# netstat -tunlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1009514/sshd        
tcp6       0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN      2803472/productivit 
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      1017657/httpd       
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1017657/httpd       
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1009514/sshd        
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           1009281/chronyd     
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                1009281/chronyd
```

I periodically restart the service to renew the let's encrypt certs

```
[root@productivity ~]# cat restart-productivity.sh 
#!/bin/sh
pkill "productivity"
bash -c "exec -a productivity java -jar productivity.jar -Dkeystore.location=./ssl/productivity.to.keystore . & disown &"
```

This worked like a charm for months. Now, even when I manually run `pkill productivity` the service does not get killed. I can only kill the service by calling `kill PID`. This does work but is useless for automation.

I'm running on CentOS 8 and I'm clueless why it stopped working. Can anyone help me out here?

UPDATE

```
[root@productivity ecommerce]# ps aux | grep productivity
root     2803472  1.3 10.3 2648228 204168 pts/1  Sl   20:24   0:21 productivity -jar productivity.jar -Dkeystore.location=./ssl/productivity.to.keystore .
root     2803848  0.0  0.0  11800  1152 pts/1    S+   20:49   0:00 grep --color=auto productivity
```

Comment: If you're on CentOS 8, you have systemd. Use that for process supervision, don't try to roll your own. Once you define a `productivity.service` with an `ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar productivity.jar -Dkeystore.location=./ssl/productivity.to.keystore .`, you get `systemctl restart productivity` for free, not to mention all the other commands (`systemctl status productivity`, or `journalctl -u productivity` to read its logs, etc).

Comment: Please add output of `ps aux | grep productivity` to your question. No comment.

Comment: Updated my question with `ps aux | grep productivity` result

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for me in the end was

```
#!/bin/sh
PID=`pidof productivity`
kill $PID
bash -c "exec -a productivity java -jar productivity.jar . & disown &"
```

Answer (score 3):

I use `kill` to send **SIGTERM** to most processes.
I don't use `pkill` any more, instead I prefer `pgrep` combined with `kill` ...

```
pgrep -io "PROCESSNAME" | xargs kill
```

The `-i` is to check for case insensitive
and `-o` is to output first process ID only.

You can use this as an `alias` in your `~/.bashrc_aliases` or direct in your `~/.bashrc`.
For example I use that to kill discord cause it will not halt on its own.

```
alias kill_discord='pgrep -io discord | xargs kill'
```

Just my 2cents.

**Update**

Rule of thumb for killing processes.

1. **SIGTERM** is trying to shutdown a process the normal way.
2. when **SIGTERM** doesn't work you can try **SIGINT**. This is an interrupt like *CTRL-C*.
3. if neither of those signal work you can try **SIGHUP**. This signal is send to processes when closing a terminal. Daemons will reload their config-files.
4. Last but not least there is **SIGKILL**. This will kill any process no matter what, and it should only be used when a process isn't responding any more.

```
kill {-2|-INT|-SIGINT|-s 2|-s INT|-s SIGINT|--signal 2|--signal INT|--signal SIGINT} [PID]
kill {-1|-HUP|-SIGHUP|-s 1|-s HUP|-s SIGHUP|--signal 1|--signal HUP|--signal SIGHUP} [PID]
kill {-9|-KILL|-SIGKILL|-s 9|-s KILL|-s SIGKILL|--signal 9|--signal KILL|--singal SIGKILL} [PID]
```

Comment: It's not kiling the service either `#!/bin/sh
pgrep -io "productivity" | xargs kill
bash -c "exec -a productivity java -jar productivity.jar -Dkeystore.location=./ssl/productivity.to.keystore . & disown &"`

Comment: does `pgrep -io "productivity"` find an PID ?

Comment: No : / it executes but shoes no result. I guess I'll have to add a service as described by `@Charles Duffy`

Comment: You looking for the wrong process then ! Have you tried `pgerp` to search for the cmd `ps` is providing ? Charle's example is a good solution, but it is a complete other approach and wont fix the fact you searching for the wrong process atm.

Comment: `exec -a productivity` defines the name of the process and `ps aux | grep productivity`does show me `.. 0:21 productivity -jar ..` so, if I connect the dots right, it should work. It used to work when I set it up and I can't figure out why it stopped working